# what is the difference between coin battery and alkaline battery

Tags: batteries, coin-cell, alkaline

i'm quite curious with coin battery and alkaline battery. I have submerge 2 coin battery into the water and the battery short circuit and damaged after a while. While i put 2 alkaline battery into the water, but they still can perform well. i wonder why both type of battery is short circuit, but only coin battery will damage. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **"Coin"** is a physical "form factor" or shape of a battery cell. The more common form factor is a cylinder (like a AA cell, etc.)
- **Alkaline** is a type of CHEMISTRY of the battery cell. Different chemistries of batteries can be found in various form-factors. There is no particular correlation between the form-factor and the chemistry of a battery cell.

Whether a particular battery cell can survive **under water** has nothing to do with its form-factor or its chemistry.  Most batteries are not designed to operate submerged under water. No matter what size, shape, or chemistry they are.

Answer (score 0):

With this answer I assumed:

- With alkaline you mean a AA, AAA, C, D etc cell.
- For the coin cell the chemistry does not matter.

It's about the distance between the positive and negative terminal. The distance between the positive and negative of the coin cell are closer together then the positive and negative of the AA cell. This means the AA cell has more water in between the two points and thereby a higher resistance and a lower leak current.

Don't use batteries under water, they are not designed to.